# Why request status is 200 OK but RED?

Tags: java, rest, httprequest

I have a web service which returns two different type of responses:

`text/plain` and `application/octet-stream`

the web service code:

```
@GET
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN })
    @Path("/getUpdate")
    public Response getUpdate(@QueryParam("softwareId") String softwareId, @QueryParam("version") String version, @QueryParam("osNameCode") int osNameCode,
            @QueryParam("osArchCode") int osArchCode) {

        File file = Utils.getUpdateFile(version, osNameCode, osArchCode);
        if (file != null)
            return Response.status(200).entity(file).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
                    .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"").build();
        else
            return Response.status(200).entity("No File").type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).build();
    }
```

if the response type is `application/octet-stream` the status is 200 OK and I get file successfully but in Chrome's network color of request is red!

I call the web service by typing its address in the browser:

`http://localhost:8080/SSS/update/getUpdate?softwareId=SSS&version=1.1.2&osNameCode=2&osArchCode=1`

[image]

Any Idea?

Comment: Some screenshots would be very useful.

Comment: It seems that the content size is 0 (difficult to read)

Comment: Click on the link to get more details about it.

Comment: My guess is that Chrome finds suspects that a GET request has an empty result. Can you try to return a non-empty content?

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle, I even added content-length header with size of file but no differences

Comment: Try replacing `MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN` with `"text/plain; charset=UTF-8"`.  Remember to change it both in the `return` statement and in the `@Produces` annotation.  You may also want to consider returning `Response.noContent()` or `Response.status(Reponse.Status.NOT_FOUND)` rather than returning valid content.